# R match dataframe and concatenate values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following 2 dataframes: df1 and df2.

```
df1 <- data.frame("name" = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), "col1" = c("s", "t", "u","v","w"))


df2 <- data.frame("name" = c("a", "b", "b"), "col2" =  c(1, 2, 3))
```

For each row of df2, I want to check if there is a match between the values in the "name" columns of both dataframes. If this is the case, the value of col2 and col1 should be concatenated together. The output would be written into a new dataframe df3, that would look like this

```
> output
  name col3
1    a  s:1
2    a  t:1
3    b  u:2
4    b  v:2
5    b  w:2
6    b  u:3
7    b  v:3
8    b  w:3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` and create a new `data.frame` where you `paste` `col1` and `col2`.

```
with(merge(df1, df2), data.frame(name, col3=paste(col1, col2, sep=":")))
#  name col3
#1    a  s:1
#2    a  t:1
#3    b  u:2
#4    b  u:3
#5    b  v:2
#6    b  v:3
#7    b  w:2
#8    b  w:3
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, .(name, col3 = paste(col1, col2, sep=":")), on = .(name)]
#   name col3
#1:    a  s:1
#2:    a  t:1
#3:    b  u:2
#4:    b  v:2
#5:    b  w:2
#6:    b  u:3
#7:    b  v:3
#8:    b  w:3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `left_join` `df1` and `df2` `by = "name"` and combine the columns using `unite` to create new column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = "name") %>% unite(col3, col1, col2, sep = ":")

#  name col3
#1    a  s:1
#2    a  t:1
#3    b  u:2
#4    b  u:3
#5    b  v:2
#6    b  v:3
#7    b  w:2
#8    b  w:3
```

Or in base R

```
transform(merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE), col3 = paste(col1, col2, sep = ":"))
```